# Salesforce API is returning only 500 rows when queried via SOQL using Python

Tags: python, salesforce, soql

I am working on a Python Script to get the data out from sales force. Everything seems to be working fine I am passing a custom SOQL query to get the data but the challenge is that query is returning only the first 500 rows but there are close to 653000 results inside my object.

"data= sf.query('SELECT {} from  abc'.format(','.join(column_names_list)))"

now i tried using querymore() and queryall() but that doesn't seem to work too.

At the end my intent is to load all this information in a dataframe and push this to a table and keep looking for new records by scheduling this code. Is there a way to achieve this. ?

Comment: "data= sf.query('SELECT {} from abc limit 1000'.format(','.join(column_names_list)))" try that ?

Comment: Check out the SOQL section: http://tomhayden3.com/2013/08/04/salesforce-python/

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve all the records using a single method just try

```
data= sf.query_all('SELECT {} from abc'.format(','.join(column_names_list)))
```

Refer following [link](https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/)